# Probablity_expectation_doubt

Tags: probability, expectation

A coin is biased so that the probability a head comes up when it is ﬂipped is 0.6. What is the expected number of heads that come up when it is ﬂipped 10 times?
My approach and doubt-:
 can't i use bernouli trials formula(n*p)
n=10
p=0.6
is 6 the answer ? if not then what is the correct answer?

Comment: Your approach is correct.

Comment: Won't effect given it is biassed!!?

Comment: It is not necessary that $p=0.5$ in Bernoulli trials, it can be any valid probability, and the formula for mean and variance remain $np$ and $npq$ respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ denote the number of heads, then:

- $P(X=n)=\binom{10}{n}\cdot(0.6)^{n}\cdot(1-0.6)^{10-n}$
- $E(X)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{10}n\cdot\binom{10}{n}\cdot(0.6)^{n}\cdot(1-0.6)^{10-n}=6$